# Update sql temp table column with computational expression

Tags: sql, sql-server

I perform the SQL code below. Although computational expression is not Zero, all rows update with zero, as an additional information denominator is bigger in every cases.

```
UPDATE #t
SET ProportionOfvehicle = (CountOfVehicle / @TotalNumberOfPrivateVehicles)*100
WHERE LegalPersonID IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: At a pure guess: This is very likely what we call "integer" maths. `9/10=0` where as `9.0/10.0=0.9`. This is because SQL Server (and many other applications) will use the same datatype throughout an expression if that are all the same. `0.9` **cannot** be represented as an Integer, so the decimal part is stripped off; giving `0`. If the data types differ, SQL Server uses something call "Data Type Precendence" (Google it). Sample DDL and DML, along with a value for `@TotalNumberOfPrivateVehicles` that **replicates** the problem and your expected results will greatly help us help you.

Comment: I'm personally wondering how someone can "own"(?) less than a whole vehicle, @Xaphas . :)

Comment: In the same way that someone can own a part of a living horse??

Comment: `1.0 * CountOfVehicle` to get numeric math; `1e * CountOfVehicle` to get floating-point. An explicit `CONVERT` is also possible, and recommended if your target type is `NUMERIC`, since precision and scale are otherwise implicitly determined.

Comment: share your sample data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could finally solved the problem by my self. I created a temp table which the data type for its computational fields are float like below

```
**CREATE TABLE #t
(
    CountOfVehicle BIGINT,
    LegalPersonID BIGINT,
    RegionID BIGINT,
    ProportionOfvehicle FLOAT,
    ProportionOfAccident FLOAT,
    ProportionOfPersonel FLOAT
)**
```

then insert into it for other fields except computational fields with code below

```
**INSERT  INTO #t
(
    CountOfVehicle,
    LegalPersonID,
    RegionID,
    ProportionOfvehicle,
    ProportionOfAccident,
    ProportionOfPersonel
)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CountOfVehicle,
       LegalPersonID,
       RegionID,
       NULL AS ProportionOfvehicle,
       NULL AS ProportionOfAccident,
       NULL AS ProportionOfPersonel
FROM Bus.VehicleOwnerships
WHERE OwnershipTypeValue IN (1,2)
GROUP BY LegalPersonID,
         RegionID**
```

and finally update the computational fields with the statement below

```
**UPDATE #t
SET ProportionOfvehicle = CountOfVehicle / @TotalNumberOfOrganizationVehicles
WHERE RegionID IS NOT NUL**
```